# In CLion, What is the difference between Qt Console and Qt Widgets Executable project templates

Tags: qt, clion, qtwidgets, qtconsole

In CLion, What is the difference between Qt Console and Qt Widgets Executable project templates.
My intuition is that Qt Console is CLI and Widgets is GUI, but googling hasn't confirmed this. I'm hoping this QnA will help future googlers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Console" means text-based (which doesn't prevent it from opening windows or showing dialogs). On some platforms (e.g. Windows) this will force a "console" or terminal window to appear.

The "widgets" template is a pure GUI application (which doesn't stop it from manually opening a "console" or text-window on supported platforms).